GPU management using Tensorflow and Ray clients (OOM)
I am using Ray to simulate several clients learning with Tensorflow (for a federated learning task with Flower). Ray allows the GPU to be shared between the clients. The GPU is therefore divided into N parts, N being the number of client + 1 (for the server). I use 2 GPU (v100-32G) for a MNIST classification task. I think these GPUs should be enough for this dataset...
Clients are successively selected to make an epoch.
In this case, the first epoch is successfully done by the first 3 clients. OOM occurs when trying to launch the first epoch with the next 3 clients.
It feels like memory is not released from the first epoch of first 3 clients.
Here, Ray initialization:
    client_resources = {
            "num_cpus": 1.0,
            "num_gpus": 1.0 / (nbClient+1)
    }


    result=fl.simulation.start_simulation(
      client_fn=client_training_fn,
      num_clients=min_available_clients,
      config=fl.server.ServerConfig(num_rounds=FLAGS.num_rounds),
      strategy=strategy,
      ray_init_args=ray_server_config,
      client_resources=client_resources,
    )

The client_training_fn() function is the following:

    def fit(self, parameters, config):
            """
            Fit the client model.
    
            :param parameters: Model parameters.
            :param config: Configuration dictionary.
            :return: Tuple containing updated model parameters, number of training samples, and a dictionary of log metrics.
            """
            print('#################### FlClient.fit new round')
            #try to load warm start info
            self.load_restart_config()
            
            #set updated weights
            self.model.set_weights(parameters)
            # define each callbacks
            if self.round>0:
                self.all_callbacks_dict=define_callbacks(self.settings, self.model, self.val_data, self.train_iterations_per_epoch, self.file_writer, self.log_dir, metrics=self.metrics, previous_model_params=self.model.get_weights(), initial_value_threshold=self.initial_value_threshold)
    
            #training for one epoch
            history=self.model.fit(
                x=self.train_data,
                y=None,#train_data,
                batch_size=None,
                epochs=self.settings.nbEpoch*(self.round+1),
                verbose=1,
                callbacks=self.all_callbacks_dict.values(),
                validation_split=0.0,
                validation_data=self.val_data, #=> done at the evaluate method level
                shuffle=True,
                class_weight=None,
                sample_weight=None,
                initial_epoch=self.round*self.settings.nbEpoch,
                steps_per_epoch=self.train_iterations_per_epoch,
                validation_steps=self.val_iterations_per_epoch,
                validation_freq=1,
                max_queue_size=self.workers*100,
                workers=self.workers,
                use_multiprocessing=False,
            )
            
            self.model.track_weights_change(parameters, self.round)
            print('Client fit step done')
            print('-> FlClient.fit round result, history=', self.round,history.history)
            
            # prepare emitted logs
            last_model_parameters=self.get_parameters()
            fit_log = { key:history.history[key][-1] for key in history.history.keys()} #{k: np.mean(v) for k, v in history.history.items()}
            second_network= parameters,                                                       return_drt_product=True)[0])
            
            return self.model.get_weights(), int(self.train_iterations_per_epoch*self.settings.batch_size), fit_log


I encounter an Out Of Memory (OOM) error as soon as the learning task begins.
Some logs now.
This first block of log shows ray initialization:
INFO:flwr:Flower VCE: Ray initialized with resources: {'node:__internal_head__': 1.0, 'object_store_memory': 47982607564.0, 'CPU': 6.0, 'accelerator_type:V100': 1.0, 'memory': 101959417652.0, 'node:10.159
.28.19': 1.0, 'GPU': 1.0}
INFO flwr 2024-04-03 09:19:13,892 | app.py:219 | Optimize your simulation with Flower VCE: https://flower.dev/docs/framework/how-to-run-simulations.html
INFO:flwr:Optimize your simulation with Flower VCE: https://flower.dev/docs/framework/how-to-run-simulations.html
INFO flwr 2024-04-03 09:19:13,893 | app.py:242 | Flower VCE: Resources for each Virtual Client: {'num_cpus': 1, 'num_gpus': 0.25}
INFO:flwr:Flower VCE: Resources for each Virtual Client: {'num_cpus': 1, 'num_gpus': 0.25}
INFO flwr 2024-04-03 09:19:13,909 | app.py:288 | Flower VCE: Creating VirtualClientEngineActorPool with 4 actors
INFO:flwr:Flower VCE: Creating VirtualClientEngineActorPool with 4 actors
INFO flwr 2024-04-03 09:19:13,909 | server.py:89 | Initializing global parameters
INFO:flwr:Initializing global parameters
INFO flwr 2024-04-03 09:19:13,909 | server.py:272 | Using initial parameters provided by strategy
INFO:flwr:Using initial parameters provided by strategy
INFO flwr 2024-04-03 09:19:13,909 | server.py:91 | Evaluating initial parameters
INFO:flwr:Evaluating initial parameters
(pid=122610) 2024-04-03 09:19:15.256799: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:111] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors
 from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
(pid=122610) 2024-04-03 09:19:15.312789: E tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:9342] Unable to register cuDNN factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuDNN when one 
has already been registered
(pid=122610) 2024-04-03 09:19:15.312866: E tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_fft.cc:609] Unable to register cuFFT factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuFFT when one h
as already been registered
(pid=122610) 2024-04-03 09:19:15.312905: E tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1518] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when o
ne has already been registered
(pid=122610) 2024-04-03 09:19:15.322076: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operation
s.
(pid=122610) To enable the following instructions: AVX2 AVX512F AVX512_VNNI FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2024-04-03 09:19:15.658283: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:442] Loaded cuDNN version 8600
2024-04-03 09:19:18.843363: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x145d2352d3c0 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2024-04-03 09:19:18.843399: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Tesla V100-SXM2-32GB, Compute Capability 7.0
2024-04-03 09:19:18.849104: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tensorflow/utils/dump_mlir_util.cc:269] disabling MLIR crash reproducer, set env var `MLIR_CRASH_REPRODUCER_DIRECTORY` to enable.
2024-04-03 09:19:18.972353: I ./tensorflow/compiler/jit/device_compiler.h:186] Compiled cluster using XLA!  This line is logged at most once for the lifetime of the process.
2024-04-03 09:19:24.802109: I tensorflow/core/grappler/devices.cc:66] Number of eligible GPUs (core count >= 8, compute capability >= 0.0): 2
2024-04-03 09:19:24.802246: I tensorflow/core/grappler/clusters/single_machine.cc:361] Starting new session
2024-04-03 09:19:24.804793: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1886] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 31141 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: Tesla V100-SXM2-
32GB, pci bus id: 0000:88:00.0, compute capability: 7.0
2024-04-03 09:19:24.805063: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1886] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1 with 31141 MB memory:  -> device: 1, name: Tesla V100-SXM2-
32GB, pci bus id: 0000:8a:00.0, compute capability: 7.0
2024-04-03 09:19:24.945746: I tensorflow/core/grappler/devices.cc:66] Number of eligible GPUs (core count >= 8, compute capability >= 0.0): 2
2024-04-03 09:19:24.945880: I tensorflow/core/grappler/clusters/single_machine.cc:361] Starting new session
2024-04-03 09:19:24.948445: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1886] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 31141 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: Tesla V100-SXM2-
32GB, pci bus id: 0000:88:00.0, compute capability: 7.0
2024-04-03 09:19:24.948723: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1886] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1 with 31141 MB memory:  -> device: 1, name: Tesla V100-SXM2-
32GB, pci bus id: 0000:8a:00.0, compute capability: 7.0
2024-04-03 09:19:25.014613: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/convert/trt_optimization_pass.cc:186] Calibration with FP32 or FP16 is not implemented. Falling back to use_calibration = False.Note that the 
default value of use_calibration is True.
2024-04-03 09:19:25.027349: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/segment/segment.cc:970]

And then, the OOM:
(DefaultActor pid=122610)   warnings.warn(
(DefaultActor pid=122610)   if (distutils.version.LooseVersion(tf.version.VERSION) <
(DefaultActor pid=122610) 2024-04-03 09:19:29.144727: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1886] Created device /device:GPU:0 with 452 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: Tesla V100-SXM2-
32GB, pci bus id: 0000:88:00.0, compute capability: 7.0
(DefaultActor pid=122610) 2024-04-03 09:19:29.147653: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1886] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 452 MB memory:  -> de
vice: 0, name: Tesla V100-SXM2-32GB, pci bus id: 0000:88:00.0, compute capability: 7.0
(DefaultActor pid=122610) 2024-04-03 09:19:29.149885: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1886] Created device /device:GPU:0 with 452 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: Tesla V100-SXM2-
32GB, pci bus id: 0000:88:00.0, compute capability: 7.0
(DefaultActor pid=122610) 2024-04-03 09:19:29.151743: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1886] Created device /device:GPU:0 with 452 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: Tesla V100-SXM2-
32GB, pci bus id: 0000:88:00.0, compute capability: 7.0
(DefaultActor pid=122610) 2024-04-03 09:19:29.546670: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:746] failed to allocate 452.62MiB (474611712 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_O
F_MEMORY: out of memory
(DefaultActor pid=122610) 2024-04-03 09:19:29.546829: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:746] failed to allocate 407.36MiB (427150592 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_O
F_MEMORY: out of memory
(DefaultActor pid=122610) 2024-04-03 09:19:29.546939: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:746] failed to allocate 366.63MiB (384435712 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_O
F_MEMORY: out of memory
(DefaultActor pid=122610) 2024-04-03 09:19:29.547042: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:746] failed to allocate 329.96MiB (345992192 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_O
F_MEMORY: out of memory
(DefaultActor pid=122610) 2024-04-03 09:19:29.547143: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:746] failed to allocate 296.97MiB (311393024 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_O
F_MEMORY: out of memory
(DefaultActor pid=122610) 2024-04-03 09:19:29.547242: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:746] failed to allocate 267.27MiB (280253952 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_O
F_MEMORY: out of memory
(DefaultActor pid=122610) 2024-04-03 09:19:29.547341: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:746] failed to allocate 240.54MiB (252228608 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_O
F_MEMORY: out of memory
(DefaultActor pid=122610) 2024-04-03 09:19:29.547440: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:746] failed to allocate 216.49MiB (227005952 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_O
F_MEMORY: out of memory
(DefaultActor pid=122610) 2024-04-03 09:19:29.547545: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:746] failed to allocate 194.84MiB (204305408 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_O
F_MEMORY: out of memory
(DefaultActor pid=122610) 2024-04-03 09:19:29.548136: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:746] failed to allocate 175.36MiB (183875072 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_O
F_MEMORY: out of memory
(DefaultActor pid=122610) 2024-04-03 09:19:29.548238: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:746] failed to allocate 157.82MiB (165487616 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_O
F_MEMORY: out of memory
(DefaultActor pid=122610) 2024-04-03 09:19:29.548335: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:746] failed to allocate 142.04MiB (148939008 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_O
F_MEMORY: out of memory
(DefaultActor pid=122610) 2024-04-03 09:19:29.548432: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:746] failed to allocate 127.83MiB (134045184 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_O
F_MEMORY: out of memory
(DefaultActor pid=122610) 2024-04-03 09:19:29.548539: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:746] failed to allocate 115.05MiB (120640768 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_O
F_MEMORY: out of memory

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 821, in from_tensor_slices
    return from_tensor_slices_op._from_tensor_slices(tensors, name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/from_tensor_slices_op.py", line 25, in _from_tensor_slices
    return _TensorSliceDataset(tensors, name=name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/from_tensor_slices_op.py", line 33, in __init__
    element = structure.normalize_element(element)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/util/structure.py", line 110, in normalize_element
    ops.convert_to_tensor(t, name="component_%d" % i))
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/profiler/trace.py", line 183, in wrapped
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 698, in convert_to_tensor
    return tensor_conversion_registry.convert(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_conversion_registry.py", line 234, in convert
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 328, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 267, in constant
    return _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape=False,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 279, in _constant_impl
    return _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 289, in _constant_eager_impl
    t = convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 102, in convert_to_eager_tensor
    return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Failed copying input tensor from /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 in order to run _EagerConst: Dst tensor is not initialized.


(DefaultActor pid=122608) 2024-04-03 09:19:39.561084: W tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:485] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 33.67MiB (rounded to 35305216)requested by op _EagerConst
(DefaultActor pid=122608) If the cause is memory fragmentation maybe the environment variable 'TF_GPU_ALLOCATOR=cuda_malloc_async' will improve the situation. 
(DefaultActor pid=122608) Current allocation summary follows.
(DefaultActor pid=122608) Current allocation summary follows.
(DefaultActor pid=122608) 2024-04-03 09:19:39.561097: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1039] BFCAllocator dump for GPU_0_bfc
(DefaultActor pid=122608) 2024-04-03 09:19:39.561110: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (256):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
(DefaultActor pid=122608) 2024-04-03 09:19:39.561122: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (512):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
(DefaultActor pid=122608) 2024-04-03 09:19:39.561133: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (1024):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
(DefaultActor pid=122608) 2024-04-03 09:19:39.561144: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (2048):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
(DefaultActor pid=122608) 2024-04-03 09:19:39.561155: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (4096):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
(DefaultActor pid=122608) 2024-04-03 09:19:39.561166: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (8192):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
(DefaultActor pid=122608) 2024-04-03 09:19:39.561176: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (16384):    Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
(DefaultActor pid=122608) 2024-04-03 09:19:39.561187: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (32768):    Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
(DefaultActor pid=122608) 2024-04-03 09:19:39.561198: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (65536):    Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
(DefaultActor pid=122608) 2024-04-03 09:19:39.561209: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (131072):   Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
(DefaultActor pid=122608) 2024-04-03 09:19:39.561220: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (262144):   Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
(DefaultActor pid=122608) 2024-04-03 09:19:39.561231: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (524288):   Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
(DefaultActor pid=122608) 2024-04-03 09:19:39.561241: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (1048576):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
(DefaultActor pid=122608) 2024-04-03 09:19:39.561253: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (2097152):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
(DefaultActor pid=122608) 2024-04-03 09:19:39.561264: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (4194304):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
(DefaultActor pid=122608) 2024-04-03 09:19:39.561274: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (8388608):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
(DefaultActor pid=122608) 2024-04-03 09:19:39.561285: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (16777216):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
(DefaultActor pid=122608) 2024-04-03 09:19:39.561296: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (33554432):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
(DefaultActor pid=122608) 2024-04-03 09:19:39.561307: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (67108864):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
(DefaultActor pid=122608) 2024-04-03 09:19:39.561318: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (134217728):    Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
(DefaultActor pid=122608) 2024-04-03 09:19:39.561329: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (268435456):    Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
(DefaultActor pid=122608) 2024-04-03 09:19:39.561342: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1062] Bin for 33.67MiB was 32.00MiB, Chunk State: 
(DefaultActor pid=122608) 2024-04-03 09:19:39.561352: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1100]      Summary of in-use Chunks by size: 
(DefaultActor pid=122608) 2024-04-03 09:19:39.561362: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1107] Sum Total of in-use chunks: 0B
(DefaultActor pid=122608) 2024-04-03 09:19:39.561373: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1109] Total bytes in pool: 0 memory_limit_: 110755840 available bytes: 110755840 curr_region_allocation_bytes_: 110755840
(DefaultActor pid=122608) 2024-04-03 09:19:39.561387: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1114] Stats: 
(DefaultActor pid=122608) Limit:                       110755840
(DefaultActor pid=122608) InUse:                               0
(DefaultActor pid=122608) MaxInUse:                            0
(DefaultActor pid=122608) NumAllocs:                           0
(DefaultActor pid=122608) MaxAllocSize:                        0
(DefaultActor pid=122608) Reserved:                            0
(DefaultActor pid=122608) PeakReserved:                        0
(DefaultActor pid=122608) LargestFreeBlock:                    0
(DefaultActor pid=122608) 2024-04-03 09:19:39.561398: W tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:497] <allocator contains no memory>



The most surprising part for me is to see that a device is created with 452MB when I have a 32G GPU:
Created device /device:GPU:0 with 452 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: Tesla V100-SXM2-
But maybe I don't understand what happens here.
OOMs are common errors online and batch size seems to be a recurring factor. I tried to reduce my batch size to 1, but not visible effect on my issue.

This is just a wild guess, but by default TensorFlow grabs all available GPU memory on start. Maybe this clashes with the fact that you seems to give every job 1/4th of a GPU. You can see how you can disable the behaviour on this page.

Nice try but same issue.
Maybe I haven't be clear on one point. Clients are successively selected to make an epoch.
In my case, the first epoch is successfully done by the first clients. OOM occurs when trying to launch the next epoch with new clients.
It feels like memory is not released from the first epoch of first clients.

How does your client_training_fn looks like?

It's quite a classic one. I added it in the question.

I looked into the flower frameworkk a bit and without understanding everything there, two things were pretty consistent: (1) the client_fn got a class that inherited from fl.client.NumPyClient, and in all examples (in the flower docs and on other pages), the number of epochs in the .fit() call was always 1. I'm not sure why, as nobody mentioned it specifically, but you mentioned that the first epoch ran sucessfully. Sorry for not having an exact solution..
